# how to point sitemap.xml to controller action

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3, sitemap

I have controller action /posts/sitemap where the sitemap is generated. Now i want to point `http//yoursite.com/sitemap.xml` to `/posts/sitemap/`

Is there any way I can changes `routes.php` to fix this.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apaches rewrite engine. Add this to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /posts/sitemap/
```

**EDIT**

Ok, after your edit I must admit, that my answer doesn't really belong to your question. I don't have much experience with Cake, but maybe adding this to your `routes.php` will help:

```
Router::parseExtensions('xml'); 
Router::connect('/sitemap', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'sitemap'));
```